# Dynamic Programming in Python - Optimal sequence

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem and unable to come up with a robust solution. Any idea, pseudo-code or a python implementation would be greatly appreciated. For sake of simplicity, consider a small matrix like in Figure 1. The rows in the matrix represent days and the columns represent minutes. We can assume that a bus travels between two points that takes 10 minutes and stops at a particular cell defined by a letter in that cell at each minute. Given the historical pattern (day 1 thru 5), we want to find the best sequence of letters. To do that we need to follow certain rules:

1. We want to select the most frequently observed letter per minute interval. If there is more than one letter with the same frequency, we can select any of them.
2. We want to maintain the continuity.
3. We want to preserve the original sequence the best we can.

We are not looking for the shortest distance (most straight line, etc.)

Here are a couple examples:
[image: Figure 1]
The sequence in Figure 1 satisfies all these rules. The highlighted sequence is just for visualization purpose. There are other ways of visualizing this sequence in Figure 1.

[image: Figure 2]
The sequence in Figure 2 is discontinuous. Hence the most frequent letters can't be stitched together. For that reason, we select the second most frequent letter in minute 3, one of the C, A, D instead of B. With that we can satisfy the rules. However, keep in mind, when 365 days used along with 100+ minutes, it gets complex. For instance, using the second most frequent letter may have resulted in rewiring the rest of the sequence.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: So the number to optimize is the frequency of the used letters? Also what do you mean with "We want to preserve the original sequence the best we can." how do you quantize that, or is that the same as "We want to select the most frequently observed letter"?

Comment: Thanks for your response, syntonym. If you look at Figure 2, the optimal sequence can't be built due to discontinuity. By replacing the letter B in Minute 3, with one of the other letters (C,D,A), we can keep the continuity in the expense of losing a point (instead of choosing B with frequency value of 2, we are choosing another letter with a value of 1). So, we are changing only one letter from the original sequence. There may be another way to satisfy the rules that would require us to replace 2 letters instead of 1. That is not what we want. We want to replace min # of letters.

Comment: And the "original sequence" ist the optimal sequence that would be created by taking the optimal char in each minute?

Comment: The original sequence is the sequence of letters with the highest frequency value at each minute cell. For instance in both figures the original sequence is 'A A B C C D C B A A', which is not the optimal sequence in Figure 2. Original sequence and optimal sequence are the same in Figure 1. However, they are not the same in Figure 2. To satisfy the rules, we need to come up with an optimal sequence that deviates from the original sequence minimally. In Figure 2, we have replaced only one letter from the original sequence to come up with the optimal sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a relative straightforward dynamic programming task.

- Start at the end: each cell in the last column gets 0 if it is the most frequent letter or 1 otherwise.
- Move on to the second last column. Each cell gets 0 if it is the most frequent letter or 1 other + min(cell_above, cell_directly_right, cell_below). Note which cell you selected.
- Repeat until you reach the end.
- You will now have in the first column one or more cells with minimal value. Follow the cells you noted in step 2.
- You now have a path from the beginning to the end which is continous and minimizes `sum([0 if cell.most_frequent else 1 for cell in cells])`

You might have to tweak the target function e.g. the last most frequent and the second most frequent letter are treated the same. Maybe you want to give a score based on how frequent they are.

Comment: Thank you, syntonym. I would probably have a target function that would score based on the difference between the max_frequency and the current cell's frequency. So, if the max frequency is 5, the cell with frequency of 3 would have a score of 2. I would really appreciate if you could provide a python source to this problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can code that on your own. If you are stuck anywhere ask a question with the specific step you are stuck on.